# inserting into a multi choice managed meta data column using lists.asmx

Tags: 2010, 2013, list, web-services

Guys i have a problem when inserting an item into a list with a multichoice taxonomy column.  I can insert terms that are already in the taxonomyhiddenlist but i cant get it to add terms that are not in the taxonomyhiddenlist.

```
<Field Name='RamNetworkMarket'>6;#;#5</Field>
<Field Name='fadbea3975d54db183c9cce5f1928e4a'>#Civils|26858d9e-bd1c-4d49-93cabc4a27eb4d69;0#Buildings|c350577b-2fd8-4e7c-8e88-fff5cdc937a3</Field>
```

Ive read that i need to put a -1 or a 0 before but it wont add the new term. Ive tried the below with no luck.  Ive also tried with a -1

```
<Field Name='RamNetworkMarket'>0;#;#6;#;#5</Field>
<Field Name='fadbea3975d54db183c9cce5f1928e4a'>0;#IT|3f3e4afd-e001-4864-b32c-f41409eaa93a;0;#Civils|26858d9e-bd1c-4d49-93ca-bc4a27eb4d69;0#Buildings|c350577b-2fd8-4e7c-8e88-fff5cdc937a3</Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must delimit your values ;# So try adding a ;# to the end of each value and make sure to use -1. Example:
-1;#label|termid;#-1;#label|termid;#